# Отправка запроса после оформления заказа OcStore (OpenCart)

Tags: php, opencart, ocstore

Необходимо после успешного оформления заказа в OcStore отправлять данные из этого заказа на внешний endpoint, предполагалось использовать curl запрос.

Проблема возникла в том, что не совсем понятно где конечный php скрипт который содержит всю необходимую информацию и в который можно дописать данный запрос.

Попробовал использовать для данной цели success.php (catalog/controller/checkout/success.php), в принципе работает но там нету массива с товарами, а как раз он мне нужен в первую очередь.

Версия OcStore: 2.3.0.2.3

Прошу подтолкнуть меня в нужном направлении.

Comment: Указывайте в вопросе версию магазина, в разных ветках структура отличается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`success.php`** - это контроллер страницы, на которую редиректит после оформления заказа. Сам заказ формируется в **`model/checkout/order.php`**. Там несколько методов, смотрите **`updateOrder`** и **`addOrderHistory`**. Они довольно большие, надо будет разбираться.

Те не менее это не самый верный способ реализовать подобный функционал. В **`Opencart`** есть система **`Событий(events)`**, которая реализует **`триггеры`** - подключение дополнительных контроллеров при наступлении различных системных событий. Формирование заказа - одно из таких событий.

[система событий](https://freecart.pro/forum/blogs/entry/12-sistema-sobyitiy-event-v-opencart-chast-1-iz-3-obrabotka-sobyitiy/)

[список триггеров](http://sv2109.com/en/article/opencart-event-system-part-3-3-list-existing-events)

Comment: Нашел файл catalog/model/checkout/order.php, попробовал внутрь метода "public function addOrder($data) {...}" вставить код который будет отправлять $data на нужный endpoint, но при оформлении заказа компилятор вообще не заходит в этот метод...

Comment: "... и addOrderHistory..."